# How to render depth-values based on the distance to the image plane in Blender

Tags: blender

I want to render a depth map of a scene in Blender (v2.65a, using the Cycles engine) that uses the distance to the image plane (or any plane parallel to it, e.g. yz-plane) as the depth value.

It is possible to use the composite nodes to render a simple depth map as described in the [documentation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Composite_Nodes/Types/Input#Using_the_Z_value_Socket). The problem here is, that the z-values used are based on the distance to the camera, not the image plane. This means that lines parallel to the image plane will have varying z-values depending on their location in the rendered image, as can be seen in this example (rendering depicts the front of a cube, values have been normalized):

[image: Depth map using the camera distance]

I want a depth map that holds the same depth for points on a plane parallel to the image plane (without changing the overall projection, since the depth map still has to coincide with the normal rendering).

This could be achieved by post-processing the current depth map using a script that corrects the values according to their angle from the view direction, but I was wondering whether there is a way to get the right information right out of the rendering process.

So is there a way to use composite nodes (or a similar Blender feature) to render a depth map based on the distance to the image plane?

Comment: Since this is an old question, I am curious If you found your answer. It appears like "Blender render" does this desired behavior as cycles and blender render have slightly different outputs.

Comment: I ended up applying a manual correction based on the angle. The scene I had was fairly simple (consisting only of planes parallel top the image plane) so that was the easiest solution.

Comment: For future questions, you could also ask in [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sure, happy to. But I think Blender Stack Exchange didn't exist when I wrote this question. Maybe it should be migrated, now that it does exist?

Comment: I flagged the question for migration through a moderator.

Comment: @MichaelMauderer I was unaware migration was possible! Thank you for this meta-informational-tidbit.